# How to prevent avahi from resolving mDNS name conflicts?

Tags: avahi, mdns

If I instruct avahi to use a host name that is already present in the network, then avahi automatically resolves this conflict by adding a `-2` to my host name.

```
Changing host name to 'foo'.
[...]
Host name conflict, retrying with foo-2
[...]
Server startup complete. Host name is foo-2.local.
```

Is there a way to disable this automatic conflict resolution?

---

Context: I have a collection of devices which may join and leave the network at any moment, and at any moment `hostname.local` should resolve to any one of my devices (assuming at least one is still on the network). If I understand RFC 6762 correctly, then [mDNS explicitly supports this use case](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6762#:%7E:text=Enforcing%20uniqueness%20of,operation%20be%20supported.):

> Enforcing uniqueness of host names is probably desirable in the
> common case, but this document does not mandate that.  It is
> permissible for a collection of coordinated hosts to agree to
> maintain multiple DNS address records with the same name, possibly
> for load-balancing or fault-tolerance reasons.  This document does
> not take a position on whether that is sensible.  It is important
> that both modes of operation be supported.

Unfortunately, avahi's automatic conflict resolution breaks this feature: if I add two devices to my network and then turn off the device that was added first, then `hostname.local` no longer resolves correctly. (`hostname-2.local` would resolve, but trying different `-X` suffices until I find one that works would be very annoying.)

I could of course have my devices monitor `hostname.local` and make them reclaim `hostname.local` if available, but that's a more complicated and error-prone solution than just having multiple devices with the same host name.